# Cypher query: find nodes having ALL their children meet some specific requirement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Take a look at http://console.neo4j.org/?id=xau632

How to write a Cypher query that will return:

- parents who only have male children (that should return John only),
- parents whose all children names start with 'P' (that should return Betty only).

Comment: What queries have you tried or what is not working?

Comment: I can easily write a query that will return Parents having Sons, or Parents having children with names starting with 'P'. But have no idea how to write them so that ALL children meet some specific condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
MATCH (p:Parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(c)
WITH p, collect(c) AS children
WHERE ALL (c IN children WHERE c:Son)
RETURN p
```

you can also filter earlier

```
MATCH (p:Parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(c)
WITH p, ALL(child IN collect(c) WHERE child:Son) as allSons
WHERE allSons = true
RETURN p
```

Comment: Das ist optimal, that's the answer I've been looking for. Thanks a lot Michael, truely appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can match properties in the related nodes from another one, here is an example (and the solution for the first query you are looking for):

```
MATCH (p:Parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s:Son)
WHERE size((p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Daugter))= 0
RETURN DISTINCT (p)
```

And, you can do it for the second one too (Check [Neo4j's documentation on WHERE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html))

In fact, you can't just ask here for two queries, you have to understand how to do them, else you won't learn cypher, that's why I gave you an example and the documentation to do the second one.

Comment: Thanks Supamiu, great answer!
I used a simplification, my case is slightly more complex, so negating all alternatives would be tricky (like "has no daughters").
I have checked that the following works as well:
"MATCH (p:Parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s:Son)
WHERE size((p)-[]->()) = size((p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Son))
RETURN p, s"
Is there any more elegant way of writing it though? Also - is it the most optimal in terms of efficiency?

Comment: I don't think this is efficient if you only want to get all parents who have no dughters, because you get the size of both `(p)-[]->()` and `(p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Son)` so you get two sets of relationships where I get only one in my WHERE clause.